# How to play YouTube videos with MPV subtitles?

Tags: youtube, subtitles, media, media-player, mpv

How to play YouTube video with MPV with subtitles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to `~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf`

```
sub-auto=fuzzy
ytdl-raw-options=ignore-config=,sub-format=en,write-sub=
```

- Note: You can change the sub-format to other language.

Comment: Doesn't work with `yt-dlp` version 2023.10.07. :/

Answer (score 0):

I just followed this [Reddit Link](https://www.reddit.com/r/mpv/comments/1367gh0/mpvconf_display_youtube_english_subtitles_either/) and it works for me. See if it works for you.

**Modify `~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf` and add the following line**

```
slang=en,eng,enUS,en-US
sub-auto=fuzzy
ytdl-raw-options=ignore-config=,sub-lang="en,eng,enUS,en-US",write-sub=,write-auto-sub=
```

**Open a Youtube video**

```
$ mpv 'https://youtu.be/hexfXc7-SsU'
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (vp9 3840x2160 24.000fps)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 (aac 2ch 44100Hz)
 (+) Subs  --sid=1 --slang=en 'English' (webvtt) (external)
File tags:
 Uploader: Travis Media
 Channel_URL: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCGPGirOab9EGy7VH4IwmWVQ
AO: [pulse] 44100Hz stereo 2ch float
VO: [gpu] 3840x2160 yuv420p
AV: 00:00:02 / 00:19:52 (0%) A-V:  0.000 Cache: 2.5s/1MB
```

It works on the auto-generated subtitle too. When the subtitle don't show up I may need to press `j` button to change subtitle language and use `v` button to toggle the subtitle visibility.